# rounding in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rounding

I want round 3 last digit of products price ,in  250,
sample: when 3 last digit of price is between 1 to 249,9 it round to 0 , when between 250 to 499.9 round to 500 , between 501 to 749.9 show 500 again and 750 to 999.9 shows 1000.
how can do it?

more desc:
I have a stored procedure that must calculate the final price of product.. when it does ,we have a number at the end like ,626300.00....now I want round that final price by 3 last digit ,if these 3 numbers are < 250 set these 3 numbers to 000,if >250 and < 500 show 500 .if >500 and < 70 show 500 again ,and if > 750 and < 999.9 show 000 and add 1 to 4th digit..

Comment: sure,I have a stored procedure that must calculate the final price of product.. when it does ,we have a number at the end like ,626300.00....now I want round that final price by 3 last digit ,if these 3 numbers are < 250 set these 3 numbers to 000,if >250 and < 500 show 500 .if >500 and < 70 show 500 again ,and if > 750 and < 999.9 show 000 and add 1 to 4th digit...

Comment: Dear @BaHaR Please Edit the question and explain it. Comments are not proper place to explain the question.

Comment: What happens when the three least-significant digits are 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your price value is stored as a number, say with type `decimal (18,2)`, you can do something like this:

```
declare @var decimal(18,2) = '324156.49'

select 
case 
    when @var%1000 between 0 and 249.9 then 1000*cast(@var /1000 as int) + 0
    when @var%1000 between 250 and 749.9 then 1000*cast(@var /1000 as int) + 500
    else 1000*cast(@var /1000 as int) + 1000
end
```

Modulo 1000 will give you the last 3 digits plus anything after decimal point. The appropriate rounding amount is then added to the thousands part of the original price.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/BRXZR72963)

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @t table (
    Val money not null primary key
);

insert into @t
values
    (7.27),
    (4.11),
    (2.83),
    (3.67);

select t.Val, floor(t.Val) + round((t.Val - floor(t.Val)) * 2, 0) / 2
from @t t;
```

Answer (score -1):

See this result.

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE (VAL INT)
INSERT INTO @TAB VALUES (1),(100),(450),(499),(750),(900),(321)

SELECT VAL,((VAL/250) + 1) * 250 yourVal FROM @TAB
```

---

Edit: Sorry about the previous answer. See below.

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE (VAL VARCHAR(40))
INSERT INTO @TAB VALUES ('1305'),('34'),('606'),('890'),('2005')

SELECT 
VAL,
((CAST(RIGHT(VAL,3) AS INT)/500) * 500) + ((CAST(RIGHT(VAL,3) AS INT)/250)%2) * 500 [yourVal]
FROM @TAB
```

Result:

[image]

---

More testing..!

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE (VAL NVARCHAR(40))
INSERT INTO @TAB VALUES ('0'),('249'),('250'),('499'),('500'),('502'),('750'),('749'),('1000'),('1002')
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This gives incorrect results for e.g. 0..259 and 500..749. You are rounding up to the nearest 250. The OP wants to round to the nearest 500.

Comment: That's better! But: **1.** Your new solution requires that the original data is provided as `NVARCHAR`, which is a somewhat counterintuitive assumption given that the question is purely about numbers. **2.** How did you choose your test data? Why didn't you choose the obvious border cases (0, 1, 249, 250, 251, 499, 500, 501, 749, 750, 751, 999, 1000, etc.)? **3.** 1000 gets rounded down to 0, which may or may not be correct (the OP's question is somewhat vague about this).

Comment: As per Rule 1000 will give 0
See the results @stakx

Comment: You are right, and my feedback is meant in exactly that spirit: Not as a test, but as an input that you can use to improve your answer, if you so choose. Don't forget that it was you yourself who asked me to _"Please see the Edit"_. And I did. If you do not wish to receive feedback, then simply do not address me. It's up to you. I'll stay quiet now.